# Coordinate ring of conics

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The question has three parts. I think i figured out the first two, but i have no idea on how to do the last.

a) Let $Y$ be the plane curve $y=x^2$. Show that $\frac{k[x,y]}{I(Y)}$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring in one variable over $k$.

Ok, so in $\frac{k[x,y]}{(f)}$ we can identify $y$ with $x^2$, making the ring isomorphic to $k[x]$.

b) Let $Z$ be the plane curve $xy = 1$. Show that $\frac{k[x,y]}{I(Z)}$ is NOT isomorphic to a polynomial ring in one variable over $k$.

$(xy-1)$ is maximal over $k[x,y]$, so $\frac{k[x,y]}{I(Z)}$ is a field. A polynomial in one variable over a field doesn't have an inverse for the variable, so it cannot be a field.

c) Let $f$ be any irreducible polynomial in $k[x,y]$,and let $W$ be the conic defined by $f$. Show that $\frac{k[x,y]}{I(W)}$ is isomorphic to $\frac{k[x,y]}{I(Y)}$ or $\frac{k[x,y]}{I(Z)}$.

I don't have any idea on how to do this.

Comment: $(xy-1)$ is not maximal. $(xy-1)\subsetneq (x-1,y-1)$, for example.

Comment: In (c), $f$ had better be quadratic, so that "the conic defined by $f$" makes sense.

Comment: At least one way I've known people to do (c) is to start with $f(x,y) = ax^2 + by^2 + cxy + dx + ey + g$ and explicitly write out coordinate changes that bring $f$ into the form $y-x^2$ or $1-xy$.

Comment: @user347489 any idea on how to do (b)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the very first exercise from Algebraic Geometry by Hartshorne. There are some solutions online.

a) as the author writes, one can consider the morphism $\phi: A(Y) \rightarrow k[x],\ \phi([f(x,y)])=f(x,x^2)$ and prove that it is linear, surjective and injective (as $\mathtt{Ker} \phi=\{[0]\}$).

b) I found three ideas one can use to show this:

1. In $k[x]$ the only invertible elements are the constants, while in $A(Z)$ both $x$ and $y$ are invertible.
2. Elements of the type $a_{rs}x^ry^s$, when considered $\mod{xy-1}$ are equivalent to $a_{rs}x^{r-s}$ if $r\geq s$ or to to $a_{rs}y^{s-r}$ if $r<s$
3. As in a), you can show that $K[x,y]/(xy-1) \cong K[x,x^{-1}] \ncong K[x]$

c) The author missed "quadratic" in the problem. Another author suggested the right path in a comment:  write $f(x,y)=ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+g$ into one of two forms above.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u21W09nsMQE from 12:50